# Find indices of numbers of interest in a vector

Tags: r

I have a long vector, let's say `A <- c(12, 16, 23, 15, 89, 43, ...)` and I would like to find the positions of some numbers in this vector, contained in another vector, `B <- c(16, 89)`.

In this example, I would like to obtain the vector `c(2,5)`. A the moment I am using a for loop, but I would really like to avoid it:

```
C <- numeric(length(B))

for (i in 1:length(C)){
      C[i] <- which(A==B[i])
  }
```

Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
x <- which(A %in% B)
#> x
#[1] 2 5
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

You can use simply:

```
match(B,A)
#[1] 2 5
```

Comment: For multiple matches of a value, `match` will just pick the first.